# Update other models field when new record adds

Tags: django, model, django-orm

I am working on Question-Answer Website.
In that i want to mark Question hasAnswered whenever new Answer adds for that question.

**Question Model**

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    uid = models.ForeignKey("User",on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default=1,related_name='user_q_id_set')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    catitle = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    editUser = models.ManyToManyField("User",related_name='user_q_edit_set',null=True,blank=True)
    hasAnswer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    qid = models.ManyToManyField("Question")
    uid = models.ForeignKey("User",on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_a_id_set')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    editUser = models.ManyToManyField("User",related_name='user_a_edit_set',null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-vote']

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.qid.hasAnswer=True
```

This is what i tried but got error

```
ValueError at /admin/qa/answer/add/
"<Answer: None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

**So how i get change hasAnswer to True whenever new Answer Adds ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that, when you try to reach questions there is no data, since first of all question entry should be created in db and then m2m relationship fields should attach. I think, the solution is to use signals - specifically [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed), where action would be `post_add`.

On the other hand, if you would like to get rid of `Question.hasAnswer` field. For question model, you can use [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional) to check if question has answers, like that:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    @cached_property
    def has_answer(self):
        return self.answer_set.exists()
```

Comment: i created hasAnswer because i want to display unanswered questions on other page.So i dont wanna check question has answer or not .I just want to save and retrive.If i use property everytime i load page it checks for all questions and it affect performance.So i think saving is good

Comment: @DEARANGEL, yes I agree on that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a field like `Question.hasAnswer` you could rather use a property for that relation:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def has_answer(self):
        return self.answers.exists()


class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    questions = models.ManyToManyField("Question", related_name="answers")
    ...
```

Comment: It works but i wanted field because everytime this performs operation , if i would field then i dont need to do operation everytime ; i would send queryset with Question.objects.filter(hasAnswer=False)